# I get error Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate

Tags: reactjs

There are many similar questions, though I am posted it here.

I am getting the following error:

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

Please note that I haven't used such functions in page.

Error occurred while selecting `Datepicker`:

```
constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state={
fields: {},
errors: {}
}
}
handleIssueDate(date){
       // this.state.IssueDate = moment(date).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
       debugger;
           let fields = this.state.fields;
           fields["IssueDate"] = moment(date).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
           this.setState({
               fields
           });
           let errors = this.state.errors;
           if (errors[date] != "" || errors[date] != null) {
               errors["IssueDate"] = "";
           }

      }
render(){
return (
<DatePicker name="IssueDate" onChange={this.handleIssueDate} selected={this.state.fields.IssueDate} value={this.state.fields.IssueDate}  placeholderText={"YYYY-MM-DD"}  />)
}
```

EDITED : 
I just removed moment function from setState. now its working fine. Please any one explain this weird error/behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you are mutating the state.

```
let fields = this.state.fields; // fields still holds the reference to the state

fields["IssueDate"] = moment(date).format("YYYY-MM-DD") // here happens the mutation

this.setState({ // state is changed again
    fields,
});

errors["IssueDate"] = ""; // state mutation once again
```

Suggested approach:

define the 'IssueDate' field inside state:

```
state = {
   fields: {
      IssueDate: null,
   },
   error: {
      IssueDate: null,
   },
}
```

and then inside your onChange func:

```
this.setState(({ fields }) => ({
   fields: {
      ...fields,
      IssueDate: moment(date).format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
   },
});
```

Do likewise with error.

Comment: thanx for reply, i tried but it not worked, i just remove moment function, and its running fine. some how its weird, do you have any reasons for the same?

Comment: @MMJ Remove everything from your onchange function, just keep: `this.setState({ date: date });` and add to your state a new field called "date", remove all other fields. If error is gone, it will mean that the problem was related with mutation.

Comment: i just removed moment date function from the handleIssueDate function. and it works fine, i just wanted to know why such weird error message thrown?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker/blob/master/docs/datepicker.md

**selected** type is **instanceOf(Date)** not a string